# Accessing data via foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models: Itasset, Location, Assetuser.
An Itasset may have a Location.
An Itasset may have an Assetuser.
An Assetuser must have a Location.

My models looks like this:

```
class Assetuser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :Location
  has_many :Itassets
end
```

```
class Itasset < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :Assetuser, optional: true
  belongs_to :Location, optional: true
end
```

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :Itassets
  has_many :Assetusers
end
```

I'm able to access the name of a location, from the assetuser table

```
<p><strong>Location:  </strong><%= @assetuser.Location.Name %></p>
```

But when I try to access the name of a location from the itasset table

```
<p><strong>Assigned Location:  </strong><%= @itasset.Location.Name %></p>
```

I receive an error

```
undefined method `Name' for nil:NilClass
```

I'd be very grateful if someone could tell me where I'm going wrong.

*Edit*
As requested, here's the schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2023_09_25_144350) do
  create_table "assetusers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "Name"
    t.string "Phone"
    t.string "Email"
    t.text "Additionalassets"
    t.text "Notes"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "Location_id", null: false
    t.index ["Location_id"], name: "index_assetusers_on_Location_id"
  end

  create_table "itassets", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "AssetTag"
    t.string "Manufacturer"
    t.string "Model"
    t.string "SerialNumber"
    t.date "PurchaseDate"
    t.integer "PurchaseCost"
    t.text "AssetNotes"
    t.string "WarrantyProvider"
    t.date "WarrantyExpiry"
    t.string "WarrantyContact"
    t.string "WarrantyEmail"
    t.string "WarrantyPhone"
    t.text "WarrantyNotes"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "Assetuser_id"
    t.integer "Location_id"
    t.index ["Assetuser_id"], name: "index_itassets_on_Assetuser_id"
    t.index ["Location_id"], name: "index_itassets_on_Location_id"
  end

  create_table "locations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "Name"
    t.string "Primarycontact"
    t.text "Address"
    t.string "Phone"
    t.string "Email"
    t.text "Notes"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "assetusers", "Locations"
  add_foreign_key "itassets", "Assetusers"
  add_foreign_key "itassets", "Locations"
end
```

Comment: can you provide the schema.rb to see if you made correct foreign keys correctly for all you models

Comment: Sure - I've edited the question to include the schema.rb

Comment: To start with you should clean up the naming issues - all your association names should be `snake_case` - eg `belongs_to :location` not `:Location` this goes for table names and column names as well. Compound names should be -CamelCased and snakecased `AssetUser` and `asset_user`. Your also need to use the `optional` correctly for the requirements outlined in the first paragraph.

Comment: As for the error - you're setting the assocation as optional yet you're not checking for the presence of a record before trying to access one of its properties. This doesn't really have so much to do with foreign keys or assocations as just good coding practices. If an assocation is optional don't just assume - because you know what they say about assumptions...